# How to use Property Sets on Snippets in Revolution

Tags: modx-revolution

If I understand MODX Revolution correctly, I should be able to make a Property Set (Tools -> Property Sets) and apply it to an element as default properties. See [rtfm.modx.com](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Properties+and+Property+Sets).

I have created a Property Set - 'tvsEnabled' - with the following values:

```
includeTVs: 1
tvPrefix: (empty string)
processTVs: 1
```

And then I call the following Snippet:

```
[[getResources@tvsEnabled? &parents=`8` &tpl=`TplArticle`]]
```

This returns nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please provide the code for `TplArticle` **tpl**, as there may be error in that tpl as well. The above code is perfectly correct.

Secondly, the `tvPrefix` parameter should be set properly. If you put an empty string, its no harm. But, try not overriding its default value. Now, if you have put an empty string, your tpl should access template variables according to the `tvPrefix` that you have provided, for e.g., `[[+name]]`. If you don't override its default value, you have to access template variables with the `+tv.` prefix, for e.g., `[[+tv.name]]`.

If this doesn't work out, please do elaborate on the total task at hand and all the pieces of codes in relation to that, which you have written.